# Truffle's artifact is undefined when running truffle migrate

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm trying to run `truffle migrate` on two js files: `1_initial_migration.js` and `2_deploy_contracts.js`. I can successfully compile my `.sol` files to `.json` ABIs but then when I try to `migrate` I get the following error:

```sh
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined
```

Here's how I've utilised `artifacts` in my js files:

```js
const { artifacts } = require("truffle");
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
```

`truffle version` results are as follows:

```sh
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.16.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Also I'm following [this course on youtube](https://youtu.be/CgXQC4dbGUE?t=1399).

I've seen a couple of posts about changing solitidy version, solc(?) version, and truffle version. I've tried downgrading my global truffle version to 5.1.39 and upgrading the solidity version at the start of my `.sol` files to ^0.6.0, as that seems to be the recommendations from those posts:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84388/solidity-0-6-0-truffle-compile-error-cannot-read-property-of-undefined

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/4191

Comment: I am also facing same issue in my project.
Can you please share the solution if you have found it?

Comment: @coder_newbie I still haven't found a solution, but I have restarted with the same youtuber but a different video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWFba_9QYmc This time I didn't run into the same issue. No idea why. The only difference is that I didn't try using `require` first - just ran `truffle migrate` while my IDE threw linting errors.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail . what exactly do you mean by `I didn't try using require first`.
And are you getting the same output as the youtuber?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same output as the youtuber (in the second video I linked in my comment). In my post above I mentioned that I included `const {artifacts} = require("truffle")`. In this latest attempt, I skipped that step. My IDE doesn't recognise where `artifacts` is coming from, but it still works because truffle is working some magic in the background. In short: try following the second video, see how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Try these files:

1_initial_migration.js:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
const YourContractName = artifacts.require("YourContractName");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(YourContractName);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything just update the truffle
Your error will be removed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).